# The scripts that I made dont work and I can't find the problem

Tags: javascript, html

First of all, sorry, I know the next code is wrong, I'm new in programming and I have a problem with it. When the user select an option from the Select, a value it must change, then, the user must write a price in numbers which value must not be higher than the previous value, here is when the scripts should act but it doesn't works. The correct code must be something like that:

```
<script>
function cboc(){ 
        var cb = $("#cbotipfon").val();
        var maxvalGORE = null;

        if(cb == 0){
            maxvalGORE = 0;
        if(cb == 15){
            maxvalGORE = 100;       
        }
        if(cb == 16){
            maxvalGORE = 200;
        }
} 

function cbocc(){ 
    var val = null;
    var x = document.GetElementById('txtprepos').value;

    val = parseInt(x); 

    if(val > maxvalGORE){
    alert('The value is higher than $' + maxvalGORE +'.'); 
    document.GetElementById('txtprepos').value = "";
    }    
}    
</script>

<select style="width=5.5em;" name="cbotipfon" id="cbotipfon" onchange="cboc()">
                    <option value="0">Select</option>                                      
                            <option value="15">Option A</option>
                            <option value="16">Option B</option>                                  
                </select>

<input type="number" onblur="cbocc()" name="txtprepos" id="txtprepos"/>
```

I've been with that problem for days. If you can help me I'll be eternally grateful. Thanks in advance and for take your time.

Comment: `GetElementById` should be `getElementById`. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your problem statement isn't very clear: what is breaking down with your script? Is there an error? Does it not properly show the alert? Or something else? Please see how to create a [mcve]

Comment: What's `cb` in your function? And what's the point of doing `parseInt("0")` instead of just `0`

Comment: @cale_b I think the scripts are the problem. After looking for answers in the website I managed to build the scripts that appear above, however, they dont work. I dont know exactly what the problem is, but I'm sure it's inside the scripts

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example. No need to declare any function. Just declare your variables correctly and use the [`addEventListener`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) method for getting the values of the `input` and `select` elements.

```js
var maxvalGORE ,val ,cb ,x = null;
document.getElementById("cbotipfon").addEventListener("change", function(){
        var cb = document.getElementById('cbotipfon').value;
        if(cb == 0){
            maxvalGORE = 0;
            }
        if(cb == 15){
            maxvalGORE = 100;       
        }
        if(cb == 16){
            maxvalGORE = 200;
        }
});

document.getElementById("txtprepos").addEventListener("change", function(){
    x = document.getElementById('txtprepos').value;
    val = parseInt(x); 
    if(val > maxvalGORE){
    alert('The value is higher than $' + maxvalGORE +'.'); 
    } else if(val == maxvalGORE) {
    alert('The value is equal to $' + maxvalGORE +'.');     
    } else {
    alert('The value is lower than $' + maxvalGORE +'.');    
    }
    document.getElementById('txtprepos').value = ""; 
});
```

```html
<select style="width=5.5em;" name="cbotipfon" id="cbotipfon">
                    <option value="0">Select</option>                                      
                            <option value="15">Option A</option>
                            <option value="16">Option B</option>                                  
                </select>

<input type="number" name="txtprepos" id="txtprepos"/>
```

Comment: It works perfectly! But when I copy and paste the code in mine, it stops working, is it in a special script? Do I need to call some specific language?

Comment: @LuisEscobar the point of the example is not to copy-paste, but to understand the functionality and work your own solution on your project.